# Как найти сумму двух или более последовательных положительных целых чисел для введенного значения

Tags: python

Не могу найти формулу для поиска сумм двух или более последовательных положительных целых чисел для введенного значения.

Например:

Введённое значение - 15.
Является последовательным числом, его можно представить как сумму двух или более последовательных чисел.

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
4 + 5 + 6 = 15
7 + 8 = 15
```

Введённое значение - 17

```
8 + 9 = 17
```

Подскажите, как находить эти суммы? Неужели перебирать все суммы от одного до ведённого значения, с последовательным увеличением на одно число начального числа?

P.S. код не нужен, нужен алгоритм, я сам хочу понять этот алгоритм.

Comment: Все перебирать не надо. а вот на формулу для суммы арифметической прогрессии нужно посмотреть обязательно

Comment: Ага, вот она как называется, арифметическая прогрессия, натыкался на неё. Благодарю, буду искать в том направлении.

Comment: Эта формула называется формула арифметической прогресии. Смотри тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Арифметическая_прогрессия

Answer (score 1):

Приведённый алгоритм квадратичный. Однако можно сделать несколько быстрее (`sqrt(sum)`, если не считать время на генерацию самих списков).

Сумма натуральных чисел от 1 до n включительно равна `Sn=n*(n+1)/2`
Сумма натуральных чисел от 1 до k, **не включая** k: `Sk=k*(k-1)/2`

Данная сумма должна представлять разность этих сумм

```
S = Sn - Sk
2*S = n*n+n-k*k+k = (n*n-k*k)+(n+k)=(n-k)*(n+k)+(n+k)=(n-k+1)*(n+k)
```

Раскладываем 2*S на все возможные пары целых множителей таких, что первый множитель не больше второго

```
2*S=p*q
p=n-k+1
q=n+k
```

Для каждой пары множителей

```
n = (p+q-1)/2
```

проверяем, что сумма в скобках делится на два, и в положительном случае находим последний член последовательности `n` и первый

```
k = q - n
```

Итого:

```
import math
def arseqs(s):
    s2 = 2 * s
    res = []
    for p in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(s2))):
        if s2 % p == 0:
            q = s2 // p
            if (q + p - 1) % 2 == 0:
                an = (q + p - 1) // 2
                a1 = q - an
                res.append([x for x in range(a1, an+1)])
    return res

for i in range(1, 37):
    print(i, arseqs(i))

 >>  15 [[7, 8], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо ещё раз, решил таким образом:

```
def count_consecutive_summers(num):
count = 1
ret = 0
while count <= num:
    s = num
    while s > 0:
        stack = int(((count*2+s-1)/2)*s)
        if stack == num:
            ret += 1
        s -= 1
    count += 1
return ret
```

Может кто посоветует как укарочить и оптимизировать код? Или пойдёт для первого взгляда?